# Как добавить в календарь метки на даты?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcalendarwidget

Всем привет. Я хочу добавить к моему календарю метки на даты, которые у меня имеются в переменной.

Полагаю, необходимо передать date_list (переменную с датами) с родительского класса в этот метод и отметить все даты на календаре.

Нашел на форуме схожий вопрос [Как изменить фон определённой ячейки в QCalendarWidget?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306144).

Я хочу сделать так же, но только чтобы вместо списка 0 и 1 сразу подавался список дат (т.к. даты могут и добавляться и удаляться с этой переменной) + сохранить окрашивание сегодняшней даты, что я уже написал в paintCell.

Вот код моего CustomCalendar.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QPoint, Qt


class MyCalendar(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)
        if date == date.currentDate():
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(122, 27, 181, 50))
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 0))
            painter.drawRect(rect)
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(110, 20, 160), 1, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap))
            painter.drawLine(rect.topRight(), rect.topLeft())
            painter.drawLine(rect.topRight(), rect.bottomRight())
            painter.drawLine(rect.bottomLeft(), rect.bottomRight())
            painter.drawLine(rect.topLeft(), rect.bottomLeft())
```

Comment: Много сумбура, вы можете конкретизировать проблему, уточнить что вы хотите сделать (может быть даже нарисовать)

Comment: Изменил описание, взгляните на вопрос

Comment: То есть, насколько я понял, вы хотите, чтобы в MyCalendar был список дат, которые надо отмечать особым образом и сам список можно было редактировать?

Comment: Да, всё верно. А также, всегда отмечать сегодняшнюю дату особым элементом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильное вкурил, то вы хотите что-то типа вот такого:

```py
class MyCalendar(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.dates = []

    def setDates(self, dates):
        # Копируем массив дат, переданных извне
        self.dates = dares[:]
        # Перерисовываем календарь
        self.updateCells()

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)        
        # Рисуем сегодняшний день
        if date == date.currentDate():
            #...
        # Иначе проверяем, находится ли дата (date) в массиве дат
        elif date in self.dates:
            # Сохраняем контекст рисования
            painter.save()
            # Рисуем дату и фон особым образом
            painter.fillRect(rect, Qt.magenta)
            # ...
            # Восстанавливаем контекст рисования
            painter.restore()
```

*Дополнение* Пример с передачей дат

```
class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(200,200,400,200)
        self.setWindowTitle("MyCalendar")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.calendar = MyCalendar()
        self.calendar.setGridVisible(True)

        self.button = QPushButton("Сlick me!")

        # Клик для генерации списка дат
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.generate)

        vbox.addWidget(self.calendar)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

    # Генерируем список дат текущего месяца для подсветки
    def generate(self):
        month = self.calendar.monthShown()
        year = self.calendar.yearShown()
        dates = []
        for i in range(randrange(10)):
            day = randrange(28)
            date = QDate(year, month, day)
            dates.append(date)
        # Передаем даты в наш календарь
        self.calendar.setDates(dates)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Window()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Кажется, это то, что нужно. Но как я могу с другого файла передать в этот метод setDates мой массив из дат, чтобы оно начало работать?

Comment: @Regulirovshik добавил пример.

Comment: Моя программа крашит, видимо, что-то не то добавляю, но Вы всё верно описали. Буду дальше развивать и избавляться от вылетаний, спасибо!

Comment: Нашёл ошибку почему крашило) У людей схожий код ошибки был. Там либо несоответствие типов, либо недостаток принимаемых переменных. Моя главная проблема была в том, что в конструкторе класса календаря не определял массив)
Отличное решение, еще раз спасибо огромное!