# Закрашивание дат в QCalendarWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcalendarwidget

Всем привет, у меня такой вопрос.
У меня дан список дат, к примеру

```
['2022-10-05', '2022-10-13',  '2022-10-14',  '2022-10-15']
```

Как мне их закрасить в календаре?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QListWidgetItem, QMessageBox, QCalendarWidget
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtCore

import sys
import tmp


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        loadUi("main.ui", self)


        self.calendarWidget.selectionChanged.connect(self.calendar_date_changed)
        self.calendar_date_changed()
        self.saveButton.clicked.connect(self.save_changes)
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.add_new_task)

    def calendar_date_changed(self):
        dateSelected = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()
        self.update_task_list(dateSelected)

    def update_task_list(self, date):
        self.tasksListWidget.clear()

        user_id = 0
        if (str(user_id) in tmp.read()["data"]["tasks"].keys()) and (str(date) in tmp.read()["data"]["tasks"][str(user_id)].keys()):
            results = tmp.read()["data"]["tasks"][str(user_id)][str(date)]
            for key in results.keys():
                item = QListWidgetItem(key)
                item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                if results[key] is True:
                    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
                elif results[key] is False:
                    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                self.tasksListWidget.addItem(item)

    def add_new_task(self):

        user_id = 0
        task = str(self.taskLineEdit.text())
        date = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()
        stat = False
        tmp.add_task(user_id, date, task, stat)
        self.update_task_list(date)
        self.taskLineEdit.clear()

    def save_changes(self):
        user_id = 0
        date = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()

        for i in range(self.tasksListWidget.count()):
            item = self.tasksListWidget.item(i)
            task = item.text()
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                tmp.edit_task_status(str(user_id), date, task, True)
            else:
                tmp.edit_task_status(str(user_id), date, task, False)

        messageBox = QMessageBox()
        messageBox.setText("Changes saved.")
        messageBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        messageBox.exec()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны унаследовать от `QCalendarWidget` и перезаписать метод `paintCell`,
эта функция имеет 3 параметра:

- `painter` - это `QPainter`, который помогает нам рисовать,
- `rect` - это `QRect`, который является прямоугольником, который представляет ячейку,
- `date` - это `QDate`, которая дает нам информацию даты, связанной с ячейкой.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QRectF 
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPainter, QFont, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCalendarWidget, QApplication


class CalendarWidget(QCalendarWidget):

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        
        _date = '{}-{:02}-{:02}'.format(* date.getDate())
        if _date in  ['2022-10-05', '2022-10-13',  '2022-10-14',  '2022-10-15']:
            painter.save()
            painter.drawEllipse(rect)
            painter.setPen(QColor(208, 34, 3))
            painter.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 12))            
            painter.drawText(QRectF(rect), Qt.TextSingleLine|Qt.AlignCenter, str(date.day()))
            painter.restore()
        else:
            QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CalendarWidget()
    w.resize(330, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Пожалуйста, ВСЕГДА предоставьте [**минимальный воспроизводимый пример**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный ответ, но есть ещё новый вопрос. 
Во-первых, как мне это вставить в MainWindow (так как у меня там были ещё иные блоки, кроме самого календаря)
Во-вторых, как быть с тем, что даты надо не обводить, а закрасить просто фон ячейки (иначе сама ячейка с датой становится нефункциональной)

Comment: @pon4ik если бы вы предоставляли минимально воспроизводимый пример, я бы попробовал в него вставить. Попробуйте сделать попытку своей реализации. Если что-то будет не получаться - зададите НОВЫЙ вопрос. Как закрашивать и т.п. можете посмотреть в других аналогичных вопросах, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306144/   Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос.